# How to show Google Review in Google Search Result?

Tags: seo

Any one know how to do this? What I mean is Review box at the right hand side: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the [Google Knowledge Graph](http://www.google.co.uk/insidesearch/features/search/knowledge.html) and Google will decide what information to show here from businesses listed in [Google Local/Google+ (Google Places)](https://www.google.co.uk/business/placesforbusiness/), data submitted to [Freebase](https://www.freebase.com) and often entries from [Wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/).

Comment: What qualifies a business to be placed there?

Comment: Google's discretion usually based on whether the search query carries enough volume to warrant placement.

Answer (score 0):

To get your Google+ Local box (that is where the data is coming from), Google needs to recognise the search term as your brand being searched. That is pretty much the only time it will come up there, as far as I know.